# python selenium hold keyboard key plus click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, safaridriver

I can sendkeys with multiple keyboard keys such as

```
element.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SHIFT, 'H')
```

But can I do something like Keys.COMMAND + click?
I tried

```
element.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND)
element.click()
```

But this doesn't work. I cannot use ActionChains because safari doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Sorry didn't see that Safari mention, anyway, I tried this and, **unbelievably** it worked

```
ctrl_click = Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER
element.send_keys(ctrl_click)
```

Comment: as I mentioned in question "I cannot use ActionChains because safari doesn't support it."

Comment: I meant mouse click not keyboard enter

Comment: Well you can't click Enter, you can't use ActionChains and you won't switch from Safari, good luck